# Htaccess RewriteRule With Same Word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

i need to redirect my directory page; but there is a folder name which starts with same word.

for example:
one of my image folder's name is **/news_images/**

and when i use the code at below; my images in /news_images/ folder doesnt work.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^news ?do=bydate
```

how can i limit this redirection to only **example.com/news** url? (my /news_images/ musnt change... )

*note: example.com/news is my news sections home page. then, i will use the news links like example.com/news/beckhams-new-goal etc..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors in your regex to avoid matching unwanted text:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/?$ ?do=bydate [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you so much.. so, could you add redirection code from news/ to /news ? (news/ folder, *without any word after)

Comment: my mail url was like this: example.com/news/... im going to use it example.com/news and example.com/news/beckhams-new-goal... *and, want to redirect old example.com/news/ url to example.com/news with 301

Comment: i have 2 line now: RewriteRule ^news/(.*) ?do=read&id=$1 .....
RewriteRule ^news/?$ ?do=listbydate [L,QSA] ..... AND NOW: i need to redirect my old main section url /news/ >>>>to>>>> /news as like: RewriteRule ^news/ /news

Comment: `RewriteRule ^news/ /news` is incorrect rule and will cause infinite looping. Do you want to redirect `/news/abcd/` to `/news/` for some reason? But that rule cannot co-exist with your already existing `RewriteRule ^news/(.*) ?do=read&id=$1` rule.

Comment: thank you so much; i find the solution with RewriteRule ^news//?$ /news [R=301,L]